# How to output 'N/A' if a value is null when retrieving max rating from a table in SQL Oracle Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle

I would need to output a the max of a rating from a table and if value is null, it would need to display N/A. However, it's not working in sql developer.

```
nvl(to_char(MAX(poi_review_rating,'N/A'))) as max_rating from my_table;
```

```
nvl(to_char(MAX(poi_review_rating,'N/A'))) as max_rating from my_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `'N/A'` as an argument of `NVL` and not of `MAX`:

```sql
nvl(to_char(MAX(poi_review_rating)),'N/A') as max_rating
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the 'N/A' parameter to nvl function instead of MAX.

```
nvl(to_char(MAX(poi_review_rating)),'N/A') as max_rating from my_table;
```